How do I perform a hello world with fission using a shell script?
Tool Context: Fission.io
Source: Fission's Github

What I am doing now:
fission function create --name hello-bash --env binary-env --code hello_bash.sh

# hello_bash.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello, from bash"

fission function test --name hello-bash
{hangs and exits with error}

-- this should work, given what I am reading on their docs, in their README.mds, and what ChatGPT is telling me.

Next I tried creating an http endpoint, but this is introducing a lot of variables. I am running locally on minikube, and am port forwarding the router at port 80 to 127.0.0.1:8080:
fission route create --function hello-bash --url /hello-bash --name hello-bash --method GET

curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/hello-bash-not-valid # errors immediately and I can see the handler got it

curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/hello-bash # I see the handler got it; indefinite hang

-- At this point I am branching out.  I've made a feature request for a shell example, put a question on here, and have inspected their go code somewhat.
I am fairly motivated for a NO-OPS solution like fission, with the main alternative being OpenFAAS. My experience with OpenFAAS was successful and immediate, but they are non free.
Any advice up to and including a complete answer would be greatly appreciated.

This was somewhat of an XY problem. I randomly thought perhaps CURL isn't behaving quite the way I wanted, or the binary-env expects, and the binary-env isn't behaving quite the way I think for all REST methods...
curl -G http://127.0.0.1:8080/hello-bash 

Worked.
